# Schwarz Lemma Proof

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, complex-integration

I'm Using [Function theory on one complex variable by Robert. E . green](http://bookzz.org/s/?q=Green%20And%20Krantz%20function%20theorey&yearFrom=&yearTo=&language=&extension=&t=0)

In the proof of the Schwarz' lemma, they have used the function $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{z}$ for all non zero $z\in\mathbb{D}$. And then the Riemann removable singularity theorem have been used. But for this  don't we need the bounded property of $g(z)$ ? if so , how to prove that $g(z)$ is bounded on $\mathbb{D}$

What I have noticed is that before proving the Riemann's removable singularity theorem we cannot say that $g(z)$ is holomorphic, thus the maximum modulus principle too can NOT be used.

Comment: That follows from $f(0)=0$.

Comment: $f(z)$ is holomorphic thus analytic around $z = 0$, and $f(0)  =0$ means it has a least a simple zero so that $\frac{f(z)}{z}$ is analytic/holomorphic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is complex differentiable in $\Bbb D$ with $f(0) = 0$, therefore
$$
 g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{z} = \frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z - 0} \to f'(0) \text{ for } z \to 0
$$
So $\lim_{z \to 0}g(z)$ exists, and then Riemann's removable singularity theorem implies that $g$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$.

Or even simpler:
$$
 \lim_{z \to 0} \, (z-0) \, g(z) = \lim_{z \to 0} \, f(z) = 0
$$
so criterion #4 in [Riemann's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem)
about removable singularities is satisfied for $g$.

Comment: @CharithJeewantha: Your comment is impossible to read. But if a function has a limit at $z_0$ then it is in particular bounded near $z_0$.

Comment: Sorry. That comment was too long. And Thank You. I got the idea..

Comment: @CharithJeewantha: You are welcome. I have added another (perhaps simpler) argument.

Comment: Thanks again.And I  added the answer below based on your first idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer, Thanks to the comment of @Martin R.
$\lim\limits_{z\to 0}g(z)=f^{'}(0)$ will imply that $\exists\delta$ such that
$$|z|<\delta\Rightarrow|g(z)-f^{'}(0)|<1\Rightarrow|g(z)|<1+|f^{'}(0)|$$

Also when $|z|\geq\delta$, $|g(z)|=\frac{|f(z)|}{|z|}\leq\frac{1}{|z|}\leq\frac{1}{\delta}$.
hence $g(z)$ is bounded.

Comment: Another way (at the point of the Schwarz lemma, one probably already knows that holomorphic functions are analytic): With $$f(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$$ for $\lvert z\rvert < 1$, we get $a_0 = f(0) = f(0)$ from the hypothesis, and then $$\frac{f(z)}{z} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_{n+1} z^n$$ has an obvious extension to a holomorphic function on the whole disk.